# two ajax posts first prevents second from working

Tags: ajax

I have a list of records representing shops.

A table structured like:

```
<tbody>                                     
<?
$sql = ...//sql to get list of shops                                    
...                 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$i++;
//puts in several variables contents of sql fields
...
?>
<tr id="<?=$id_branch;?>" <? if($i==1) echo 'class="current_active"';?>>
<td ...(styling)...<span id="th_shopname_<?=$id_branch;?>"><?=truncate($shop_name,40);?></span></td>
<td ...(styling)...<span ...id="th_address_<?=$id_branch;?>"<?=truncate($address,25);?></span></td>
etc. etc
<? } ?>
```

When you click on one of these a second part populates with details through an ajax post, and the current record is enriched with a current active class.

```
$(document).on('click', 'table tbody tr', function(e) {
        var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if($("#"+row_id).hasClass("current_active")) {
}
        else {
            $('table tbody tr').removeClass("current_active");   
            $("#"+row_id).addClass("current_active");  

                $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "ajax/account_details_container.php",
              data: {richiesta_id: row_id},
              dataType: 'html',
              success: function(html){
                    $("#account-details-container").html(html);
                    /* populates account-details-container*/

                     etc etc                
              },
            });
```

User can modify this second part and then press SAVE push button with which another ajax post is invoked to launch the update

```
$("#shop_edit_form").submit(function(e)
    {var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "ajax/edit_shop.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
               ...changes some styling...
               ...modifies first table row
                $("#th_shopname_"+data.id_shop).text(data.shop_name);
                $("#th_address_"+data.id_shop).text(data.address);
                $("#th_city_"+data.id_shop).text(data.city);
                $("#th_phone_"+data.id_shop).text(data.phone);
                $("#th_contact_"+data.id_shop).text(data.contact);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert("An error occurred. Please try again or contact administrator.");      
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });
```

Now everything works perfectly as soon as I land on the page. User can edit detail and then submit and it works.

BUT

the second ajax post STOPS WORKING, or better seems not to be even invoked if the first ajax post has just been triggered. The two ajax posts belong to different actions, are not launched one after the other automatically, but if I clic on different records in the first table so to switch from one record to another thus launching the 'onclick table...' post and then I modify and try saving by invoking the second ajax post IT DOESN'T RUN AT ALL. Moreover, in this case, the page seems to reload (I don't know if as a cause or if as a consequence of the problem). is there any reason why an ajax post can't be invoked immediately after another ajax post?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do ajax upon ajax all you want as long as you don't care if the responses get back in some random order. Is the onclick code you're expecting to run being overwritten with the response html? Is the response error-ing, choking the page so it stops working? Are you hitting F12 to see the errors that occur?

Comment: The onclick code is there. I use Chrome and in the "elements" page I can see that the SAVE button has the onclick call even when I have run the first ajax post. There is no error occurring, simply when I run the sequence (first I click on another record, then click on the first and then modify and save the details) the SAVE button doesn't invoke the onclick function. I have also added a console.log, and it is not called, nothing happens but a page reload. I believe the page reload is the hint for understanding the bug, something linked to the "preventdefault", but everything seems fine.